# How can I generate the external url for images in Sails?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

Currently, Sails serves the images hosted in assets/images folder, however, I need a different approach because the images will be hosted in a CDN system (AWS Cloudfront), so the images' URLs follow a structure like this:

```
https://hdfhhfh.cloudtfront.net/images/image.jpg
```

Therefore, **How can I approach this?, How can I approach this in order to Sails automatically generate the URL for me?**

For dev env, it's ok, for production env I need all the images in HTML/EJS to point to the CDN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thinking about how to approach this, I decided to config a reverse proxy between the client and the backend.

With Nginx I configured a rule to redirect the `/images/*` to Cloudfront endpoint, this way I've avoided placing hard code in my project.  Moreover, I have css files which are pointing to `/images/*`, with this approach I don't care about it.

Answer (score 3):

What you can do after uploading the images to S3 is:

1. In CloudFront add an alias (Alternate Domain Names) for the default https://hdfhhfh.cloudtfront.net/ like https://images.example.com/
2. In your Sails config (e.g. custom.js) add a global var like:

   images_url: 'https://images.example.com/'

then return this URL concatenated with the `images/image.jpg` e.g `${images_url}images/image.jpg` from your API to your frontend.

Comment: Yes, that’s a possible approach